# Xamarin Studio 5.5,3 can't open cshtml files

Tags: razor, xamarin

I recently updated to Xamarin Studio v. 5.5.3 and now I can't open any cshtml files. When I try to add new item (razor template) to project i get the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.
File name: 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
    at MonoDevelop.AspNet.Razor.RazorCSharpParser.Parse(Boolean storeAst, String fileName, TextReader content, Project project)
    at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.RunFirstTimeFoldUpdate(String text)
    at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.Load(String fileName, Encoding loadEncoding, Boolean reload)
    at MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.Load(String fileName)
    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.LoadFileWrapper.Invoke(String fileName)
```

The same is when i try to open any cshtml file in Xamarin Studio. I tried reinstalling and updating for several ways. I tried solutions from google but they were mostly for people who couldn't compile their projects, and my project compiles and runs just fine. The thing is I can't edit cshtml files.
I run it on Windows 7 32bit.

Someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try downgrading to an older version of Xamarin Studio.

Looking at the 5.5.3 installer (XamarinStudio-5.5.3.6-0.msi) it no longer installs the System.Web.Razor.dll, nor some other Mvc dlls. Not sure if that is deliberate or not.

Older installers, such as XamarinStudio-5.5.2.0-0.msi, do install these dlls.

This problem is also worth reporting on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)